# Setting up GitHub project on Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, github, homestead

I haven't got a lot of programming experience but I have found this open source GitHub project (https://github.com/daveroverts/bmac) but I am not sure how I can clone this to my Laravel Homestead virtual machine server.

I have initiated homestead and vagrant, which is running fine but I'm not sure how I can add the GitHub project to the server.

Would I just need to find my code folder and put the files on GitHub into a project folder or would I need to go into the virtual machine with virtual box?

Appreciate your help and sorry that my programming knowledge is so bad.

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel Homestead, you have a shared folder. Anything in that folder can be accessed both through the virtual machine and with normal browsing on your computer. You should clone the project (e.g. `project1`) into that folder. The path is listed in `Homestead.yaml`. In this example, you would then map `homestead.test` to your localhost in your hosts file, and access the site through the browser at `homestead.test`.

```
folders:
- map: ~/code/project1
  to: /home/vagrant/project1

sites:
- map: homestead.test
  to: /home/vagrant/project1/public
```

You should never have to really "go into Virtual Box" to do anything. Just use a command line to `vagrant ssh` into the virtual machine and run any commands from there. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#configuring-homestead for the full setup.